# How do i split a bitmap image in android?

Tags: android

I'm just a beginner with android. I want to divide a bitmap image into chunks and then display the image in the same way but divided. is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to break the image up into chunks you should just use:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint)
```

This will draw parts of the image. So to give the effect of breaking it up you are really just using the `src` and `dest` rectangles to draw specified parts of the images. Where `src` is the rectangle in local image coordinates of the part you want to draw and `dest` is the rectangle used to position it on the screen.

Comment: The code for breaking an image into chunks. Please correct me. Kieran.
`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView imageview=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        imageview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap drawingCache = imageview.getDrawingCache(true);
        Canvas canvas=new Canvas();
        Rect src=new Rect(23, 12, 23, 12);
        RectF dst=new RectF(0, 20, 0, 20);
        Paint paint=new Paint();
        canvas.drawBitmap(drawingCache, src, dst, paint);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to get an area of an source bitmap:

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

Comment: This is preferable if you don't need to do any further operations on the bitmaps.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a heavy method, and creating extra bitmaps could lead to unnecessary memory usage. I would recommend Kieran's answer.